# web stories category links not working in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-wordpress-pages

I have used the below code to display the web stories category-wise,
But the links not working. its returns to a 404 page

```
    `<form action=”<?php bloginfo(‘url’); ?>/” method=”get”><?php
$select = wp_dropdown_categories(‘show_option_none=Select Category&show_count=1&orderby=name&taxonomy=web_story_category&echo=0&selected=6′);
$select = preg_replace(“#<select([^>]*)>#”, “<select$1 onchange=’return this.form.submit()’>”, $select);
echo $select;
?></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `web_story_category` taxonomy in the Web Stories plugin is not currently marked as `public`, which means it can't be used to link to individual category term archives. You'd need to either use a custom taxonomy, filter the taxonomy args to make it public, or wait for a plugin update that does this.